# Docker run with -e not working.Failed to pass spring.profiles.active in the run command

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-docker-plugin

I am facing one issue with my docker file.Image build was successful but while running I am getting an error because the active profile I am setting in the run command is not reflecting.

```
# Get java
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine


VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR
COPY ${JAR} app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENV severn_js_key=1234qasw

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

My run command is like

```
sudo docker run -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev  -p 8088:80  -t tws-apps/service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in the server log while executing this statement

```
String environment = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
switch (environment) {
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to the docker container as a system environment variable. You should pass it as a [Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) instead. A solution would be to run the container by overriding the entrypoint:

```
docker run --entrypoint java -t tws-apps/service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar app.jar
```

In alternative, in your `Dockerfile` change the entrypoint. It could be a script that reads the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable and then runs Java with the var as a system property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me .Thank you